# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value on JSON net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm new to JSON in C#. I'm planning to use newtonsoft json for saving data in my game. But encountered error "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.". I don't know whats causing this. Below is my json data, models and code. What I'm trying to achieve is update a json file then save it

JSON Data

```
{"NextLevel":1}
```

Model

```
public class GameInfo 
{
    public int NextLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Code

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/testtesJSON";

var gmeInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameInfo>(path);
```

I'm getting error on DeserializeObject part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood correctly, you want to read a file from a path and then want to deserialize its content to a class object. I am assuming here testtesJSON is your file name.

You should do like this.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "testtesJSON");
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
var gmeInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameInfo>(content);
```

Based on your latest update to this question and discussion in the comment.

Its very simple, it should be like this. you can ignore the compilation errors as I have not complied with the code.

```
gmeInfo.NextLevel = 2;
var newContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gmeInfo);
File.WriteAllText(yourPath, newContent);
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that I'm trying to update a file but I just posted a code that causes errors. But I guess this is what I'm missing the ReadAllText code

Comment: @Newboy11 you mean first read the file then deserialize it then change one property then again change to string and save the new content to the original file?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: @Newboy11 its not clear by your question.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add additional details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249568/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-newboy11).